# Ajuste de divs con la altura

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Hola Tengo 2 problema soy nuevo en esto y estaba pensando en hacer unas figuras con divs:

1. Al escribir dentro de los divs mas de 7 líneas se me empieza a desarmar absolutamente todo esto pasa en la parte de naranja y en la parte ploma
2. Quiero crear una clase que se llame `textTitulo` que si se lo pongo a una span quede en negritas y mayúsculas pero al momento de separar los span quedan uno al lado del otro y la idea es que el titulo quede arriba y el resto debajo de el titulo

Para dar un ejemplo del problema 1 :

[image: Imagen al problema 1]

Para dar un ejemplo del problema 2 :

[image: Imagen al problema 2]

mi codigo Css:

```css
:root{
            --color1: rgb(241, 107, 82);
            --color2: rgb(255, 217, 131);
            --color3: rgb(90, 97, 122);
            --Seccion: rgb(216, 216, 216);
            --letra: rgb(242, 234, 234);
        }
        .wrapper {
            width: 600px;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
            grid-auto-rows: minmax(240px,auto);
            padding: 20px;
            row-gap: 10px;
        }
        .elemento {
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;;
        }
        .grupo {
            width: 100%;
            height: 70%;
            margin-bottom: 3%;
        }
        .Texto {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 75%;
            background: var(--color1);
        }
        .Triangulo{
            width: 100%;
            height: 25%;
            position: relative;
            background: var(--color1);
        }
        .objtriangulo{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: white;
            clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 40% 100%, 60% 100%);
        }
        .Seccion {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            background: var(--color3);
            width: 100%;
            height: 27%;
        }
        .textTitulo {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .Seccion > span {
            position:static;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

Codigo html:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="elemento">
            <div class="grupo">
                <div class="Texto">
                    <span>
                        linea 1<br> 
                        linea 2<br> 
                        linea 3<br> 
                        linea 4<br> 
                        linea 5<br> 
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="Triangulo">
                    <div class="objtriangulo"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Seccion">
                <span class="textTitulo">Sesion 1</span>
                    <span>Mediciones <br>e Incertidumbres</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="elemento">
            <div class="grupo">
                <div class="Texto">
                    <span>
                        linea 1<br> 
                        linea 2<br> 
                        linea 3<br> 
                        linea 4<br> 
                        linea 5<br> 
                        linea 6<br>
                        linea 7<br>
                        linea 8<br>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="Triangulo">
                    <div class="objtriangulo"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Seccion">
                    <span> <b>SESION 1</b> <br>Mediciones <br>e Incertidumbres</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Notas:

1. el triangulo es un div creado con `clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 40% 100%, 60% 100%);`
2. los elementos están creados por varias partes como se puede ver en html

Pueden ejecutarlo en: https://jsfiddle.net/Traps/h0zbj72f/

Comment: El texto se te va a desbordar siempre porque el tamaño del `grupo` lo fijaste a un `height: 70%;` cámbialo a 100%. Los `spans` quedan uno al lado de otros porque le pusiste a `Seccion` un `display:flex;`, además de que los spans son elementos de línea. Si quieres que queden uno debajo del otro agrega a  `Seccion` un `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: No entendí muy bien que resultado final quisieras lograr. Recomiendo que consideres para la próxima adjuntar una imagen de lo que quieres, aunque sea hecha en Paint.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Hola la idea es que el `height` siempre tenga un mínimo de 240px pero si el texto sobre pasa esos 240 que se ajuste por eso yo pensé en poner `grid-auto-rows: minmax(240px,auto);` pero solo funciona en el mínimo ¿se entiende?

Answer (score 0):

La solución al problema del punto 2 sería aplicar **flex-direction: column;** a la **.Seccion**

El primer punto no termino de entenderlo.